# How Do I Mine Blocks In Terraria?

Tags: terraria

How do I mine in Terraria? I know I have a pickaxe, but I am unsure of how to use it to mine anything. Do I need to equip it in a certain slot, or will it work as long as it is in my inventory? And how do I use it to mine? Do I need to click on blocks or is there a *mine* key that I need to press to use it?

Comment: If you mouse over the little up/down arrows next to your question a tool-tip will show up. I would like you to read those. Then think about them next time. Also, most games, Terraria included have their own website/wiki which includes most if not all information about the game including starting info. Which is a long way of saying RTFM next time before you ask a question. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

IF you have a pick, and you should as you start with one, make sure the slot its in is selected. Then mouse over a nearby block that you wish to break.

Your should have a mouse pointer that appears like a red corner pointer. This points to the active block

There are two modes for mining. One is like an auto mode, you just point and hold the mouse button down and it mines the area around. You can tell if you are in this mode if when you place your mouse pointer on a nearby block it has a yellow border.

In the other mode, more like a manual mode, you won't see the yellow border, but whatever you point and click on will mine.

To switch between modes simply hit your left control (typicaly marked CTRL) key. By default it will alternate, however in your settings you can make it a press and hold feature.

Another additional tip. While you are wondering around and pointing your mouse at things, try pressing the left shift key. This will autoselect the best item/tool to use given the block you are pointing at (pick, torch, glowstick, axe etc etc).

To chop trees you do the same thing except you use an axe.

There are some exceptions. You cannot mine with a normal tool the block beneath a tree or chest or altar to name a few things. Additionally some blocks are not mine-able early on because they require a special pick.

Comment: You seem to have ended your answer mid sentence

Comment: @Chippies I think I either undid it on accident or deleted it on one of the edits. I had finished the sentence....either way, I fixed it for now.

Answer (score 3):

**In Terraria, you start with 3 Copper Tools.**

1. Copper Shortsword [image: Copper Shortsword]
2. Copper Pickaxe [image: Copper Pickaxe]
3. Copper Axe [image: Copper Axe]

They all have different purposes and are used for different things.

The **Copper Shortsword** is just your regular shortsword. It is used to attack enemies. When you progress in the game, I recommend making a broadsword as it attacks a wider range of enemies than the Copper Shortsword.

The **Copper Pickaxe** is used to mine blocks. Blocks under Trees or Altars **cannot** be mined. The Copper Pickaxe can only mine blocks up to *Meteorite*, but I recommend getting a better pickaxes while you progress in the game. Use the Copper Pickaxe to mine ore and make ingots to make an anvil. After that, make better tools or weapons with it. You can make armor with it as well.

The **Copper Axe** is used to cut trees, and cannot be used to mine blocks. You collect wood to make wood products.

**Do not throw away the *Copper Pickaxe* or the *Copper Axe* before you get a better one because they are essential. Without them, you cannot cut trees or mine blocks.**

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is have a Pickaxe in your inventory somewhere, then move your mouse to a block within ~1-2 block range of your person and hold shift, this will auto equip the pickaxe, now just hold left click and you will start to mine the block under the cursor.

Alternatively put the pickaxe in the hotbar (it defaults to number 2 when you first spawn). From here just push 2 to equip it. Now if you hold left click you will start to mine any block under the cursor that is within range.
A second mode exists for mining if you push control. This will mine any block within range in the direction of your cursor, regardless of how far away the cursor is.

Answer (score 0):

put your cursor on the block you want to mine and use mouse 1. if that does not work, maybe a tree is blocking the mining of the blocks under it or you do not have a pickaxe strong enough to mine that specific material.

Comment: Consider touching up on how to equip q pickaxe, it doesn't sound like this person has even read a tutorial.